# No se pudo encontrar el tipo de proveedor de CodeDom en c#

Tags: c#, server

recurro a ustedes por el siguiente problema, estoy usando visual studio 2019, tengo una aplicación web asp.net (net.framework) con net.framework 4.5.2, mi aplicación se conecta a una base de datos uso el lenguaje c#, en mi máquina la aplicación funciona bien, pero al subirla al servidor (windows server) me marca el siguiente error:
[image: Server Error]

Cabe mencionar que al momento de compilar mi aplicación no me muestra ningún problema :/ y al momento de inspeccionar la carpeta Publish (que es en donde guarde la publicación de mi aplicación) en la carpeta **bin** veo que sí va incluida **Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.dll**, necesito ayuda :'(

Agradezco su atención.

Comment: te fijaste si el server corre la misma versiond de .net que el tuyo?

Comment: Hola @RamiroBarone sí, están en la misma versión :(

Comment: mira este link -> https://www.it-swarm-es.tech/es/c%23/no-se-pudo-ubicar-el-tipo-de-proveedor-codedom-microsoft.codedom.providers.dotnetcompilerplatform.csharpcodeprovider-.../825223213/

Comment: Hola @RamiroBarone gracias por tu aportación, solucioné el problema instalando el paquete usando NuGet, pero tengo un detalle, quisiera poder instalar el paquete Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform en mi servidor (windows server) ¿sabes cómo lo podría hacer? :/

Comment: Si tenes acceso, seguramente  es parte del Framework